# Basis of eigenvectors of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbb R_n[x]$ the vector space of polynomials with degree less or equal $n$ and we consider the linear transformation $f$ defined by
$$\forall P\in \mathbb R_n[x]\quad  f(P)=(x^2-1)P''+2xP'$$
I proved that $f$ has the spectrum
$$\mathrm{sp}(f)=\{k(k+1),\ k=0,\ldots,n\}$$
I'm stuck in this question: Prove that there's a unique basis $(P_0,\ldots,P_n)$ of $\mathbb R_n[x]$ such that:
$$\forall k=0,\ldots,n\quad P_k \ \text{is a monic polynomial with degree }\ k\ \text{which's an eigenvector of }\ f $$
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use induction.  Note that the operator is independent of $n$, so you can recycle your previous polynomials.

Comment: What do you mean by recycle the previous polynomials?

Comment: @user66407 Try writing down the basis for $n=0$, then $n=1$, then $n=2$... you'll notice very quickly what I mean by "recycle" :)

Comment: I found $P_0=1$, $P_1=x$ and $P_2=x^2-\frac1 3$ but I still don't understand the meaning

Comment: The point is that each of those expressions is independent of $n$.  In principle, you have lots of different vector spaces: $\mathbb{R}_0 [x], \mathbb{R}_1 [x], \mathbb{R}_2 [x], \ldots$, and a different linear operator for each one.  But you don't need a whole new set of eigenvectors each time.  In fact, each time you increment $n$, you keep all the old eigenvectors, and gain exactly one new one, $P_n$.

Comment: If I have a basis $(P_0,\ldots,P_{n-1})$ of eigenvectors for $\mathbb R_{n-1}[x]$ so I should complete this basis by $P_n$ to find a basis for $\mathbb R_{n}[x]$ and $P_n$ is an eigenvector of $f$. I undestand this but how can I ensure the existence of $P_n$?

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the assertion without uniqueness by completing the following sketch.

Note that for $n=0$, we need a constant $P_0 \equiv c \neq 0$ for which $f(c) = (x^2-1)c'' - 2xc' = \lambda c$. This is true for $\lambda = 0$ and $c = 1$ (or any $c$, for that matter). Hence we can set $P_0 = 1$, the unique monic polynomial of degree $0$ and the basis for $\Bbb R_0[x]$ is of course just $\{P_0\}$.

Assume that there is a unique basis $\{P_0,\ldots,P_n\}$ for $\Bbb R_n[x]$ for which $P_k$ is a monic eigenvector of $f$ of degree $k$ for $k=0,\ldots,n$. If we can extend this to a basis of $\Bbb R_{n+1}[x]$, then the result follows by induction. So we want $P_{n+1}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}a_kx^k$ such that $f(P_{n+1}) = \lambda P_{n+1}$. This last equation says that

$$
(x^2-1)\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k(k-1)a_kx^{k-2} + 2x\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}ka_kx^{k-1} = \lambda\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a_k x^k.
$$

Find $P_{n+1}$ by rewriting the left hand side of this equation in the form $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} c_kx^k$, concluding that $c_k = \lambda a_k$ for each $k$ and solving these equations for $a_k$. Requiring that $a_k = 1$ gives you only one option for the remaining coefficients.

(Edited to take into account that the basis is supposed to consist of monic polynomials.)

Comment: The polynomials are monic so we should have the uniquiness. Isn't it?

Comment: @user66407: Ha! I completely missed that word. Thanks! They are unique then, and the one I chose above ($P_0 = 1$) is the right one. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @user66407: Edited! `:)`

Comment: On the RHS of the equality there's a $\lambda$ missed, but I have one question: If I solve this equation I'll find a recursive sequence of $a_n$, how I can solve it? Thanks

Comment: @user66407: Sure thing! Did you figure the rest of the problem out (like how to determine the values of the $a_k$)? I saw your comment right before I had to run to a meeting but would be happy to help if you still have questions.